# Cannot set property height for each div in container (no jQuery!)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to set height of a container without jQuery. I came up with a  solution that sets only height property for first div (cannot do even that in jsfiddle). Please help.

https://jsfiddle.net/olivetum/x59hetL5/1/

```html
<div class="gallery">
 <div id="setWidth" class="gallery-col box shadow">Lorem</div>
 <div class="gallery-col box shadow">Lorem</div>
 <div class="gallery-col box shadow">Lorem</div>
 <div class="gallery-col box shadow">Lorem</div>
</div>
```

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.gallery-col {
  width: calc(50% - 2px);
}
.box {
  background: orange;
  margin: 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  }
```

```js
// SET GALLERY COLUMN WIDTH
    var galleryCol = document.getElementById("setWidth");
    var y = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery-col");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
      y[i].style.height = galleryCol + "px";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`galleryCol` is the element.  In your for loop, you need to set `y[i].style.height` to `galleryCol`'s height, not the element itself.

Answer (score 0):

`galleryCol` refers to the DOM element and not the height. To get it's computed height, use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to access the DOM node's height instead, i.e.:

```
var galleryColHeight = window.getComputedStyle(galleryCol).height;
```

See proof-of-concept below, where I have intentionally increased the height of the `#setWidth` element to demonstrate that other heights are based on its computed height:

```js
// Get DOM node and its computed height
var galleryCol = document.getElementById("setWidth");
var galleryColHeight = window.getComputedStyle(galleryCol).height;

// Iterate through DOM node collection
var y = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery-col");
for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
  y[i].style.height = galleryColHeight;
}
```

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.gallery-col {
  width: calc(50% - 2px);
}

.box {
  background: orange;
  margin: 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div id="setWidth" class="gallery-col box shadow">Lorem<br/>ipsum<br/>dolor<br/>sit<br/>amet</div>
  <div class="gallery-col box shadow">Lorem</div>
  <div class="gallery-col box shadow">Lorem</div>
  <div class="gallery-col box shadow">Lorem</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Now I see that I've forgot to add 'offsetWidth' to my first js line. Everything works fine now. ;)